# How can I create a mean or maximum value composite raster from a set multiple rasters in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mosaic, composite

I know of Build Virtual Raster and Merge methods which combine a set of rasters into a single raster. However, I do not know if the resultant raster is a mean or max or any other composite type. I could not find anything helpful in the documentation. Is there a way I can create a mean or maximum composite in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

You could try SAGA Mosaicking Tool in the QGIS Processing toolbox (SAGA > Raster-Tools).

In the `Overlapping Areas` section, you will find a list of options how to calculate the value for overlapping pixels (namely first, last, minimum, maximum, mean, blending boundary, and feathering).

[image]

There is a bug in the input parameters as of QGIS 3.20.3. It requires `Input File List` and ignores the selected Grids (Rasters). Please prepare an `Input File List` which is a simple text file with the full path to your raster files, one line per one raster (like `mylist.txt` in an example below).

[image]

The output will be the composite raster with maximum values (or any option you chose) in the overlapping area. You may notice a small shift in the position of the upper-light raster, to be aligned with the lower-left raster. It depends on how you set the output raster extent and cell size.

[image]